# Lm358 external voltage to output

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

Consider Lm358 connected as comparator is single supplied with 10V. What happen if some external voltage like 15V appears on output during output high?
Can a current through Q7 CB cause opening Q13 and short this ext. voltage to ground?

[image]

Source of image:

https://www.kynix.com/Blog/About-Operational-Amplifier-LM358-24-Classical-Circuits.html

Comment: Michal Podmanický - Hi, In order to comply with the Stack Exchange [rule for referencing](/help/referencing), please [edit] the question & add a link to the original source for that schematic image. To try to help you, I searched and found [this TI page](https://www.ti.com/product/LM358-N) with a very similar [image](https://www.ti.com/diagrams/custom_diagram_4_LM358-N.JPG), but it's not *exactly* the one you used. So, please link to your specific image source & remember it's your responsibility to do that in future :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The LM358 is actively trying to drive the output to a lower voltage. So even disregarding the effects on Q7/Q13, the output load will increase.

The datasheet [says in the absolute maximum ratings, footnote (3)](https://www.ti.com/document-viewer/LM358/datasheet/GUID-5E56CA30-D6B4-427A-9D41-28EAD4F85AAE):

> Short circuits from outputs to V<sub>S</sub> can cause excessive heating and eventual destruction.

Shorting the output to a higher voltage will be even worse.